# Scala method that needs either one of two implicit parameters

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I'm interested if I can create method with similar idea:

```
def myMethod[T](param: T)(implicit oneOf: Either[TypeClass1[T], TypeClass2[T]]) = oneOf match ...
```

I've tried to use default parameters (I've seen somethin similar in akka):

```
def myMethod[T](param: T)(implicit t1: TypeClass1[T] = null, t2: TypeClass2[T] = null) = 
  if (t1 == null) ...
```

However, that way I cannot force scala compiler to find at least one of them.

Also, I've implemented implicit conversion from `TypeClass1[T]` to `Left[TypeClass1[T], TypeClass2[T]]` and from `TC2` to `Right`, however Scala compiler ignores this conversions.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: What about having two overloaded methods? But, I guess that could lead to ambiguities, so probably you may also need to mix in implicit priorization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The obvious solution is to create a new typeclass that can be constructed using either `TypeClass1` or `TypeClass2`. The new typeclass implements the functionality used by `myMethod` that is common to both and maps it to the appropriate methods on `TypeClass1` or `TypeClass2`.

---

Here is an example:

```
  trait TypeClass1[T] {
    def showOne = println("Typeclass 1")
  }

  trait TypeClass2[T] {
    def showTwo = println("Typeclass 2")
  }

  trait UnionTypeClass[T] {
    def show
  }

  object UnionTypeClass {
    implicit def t1[T](implicit ev: TypeClass1[T]) = new UnionTypeClass[T] {
      def show = ev.showOne
    }

    implicit def t2[T](implicit ev: TypeClass2[T]) = new UnionTypeClass[T] {
      def show = ev.showTwo
    }
  }


  implicit object IntClass extends TypeClass1[Int]
  implicit object StringClass extends TypeClass2[String]


  def myMethod[T](param: T)(implicit ev: UnionTypeClass[T]) = {
    ev.show
  }

  myMethod(0)
  myMethod("hello")
```

This will print

```
Typeclass 1
Typeclass 2
```

Answer (score 6):

In Scala 3 you might be able to use [union type](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html) like so

```
trait Foo[A]
trait Bar[A]

given foo as Foo[Int] {}

def g[T](using Foo[T] | Bar[T]) = summon
foo[Int] // ok
```

Comment: Or `def g[T: [t] =>> Foo[t] | Bar[t]] = ???`

Comment: Or `inline def g[T] = scala.compiletime.summonFrom { case _: (Foo[T] | Bar[T]) => ??? }`

Comment: Or `inline def g[T] = scala.compiletime.summonInline[Foo[T] | Bar[T]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard `shapeless.OrElse` or `implicitbox.Priority` or `implicitlogic.Or` from one of libraries

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

https://github.com/monix/implicitbox

https://github.com/Jasper-M/implicitlogic

```
def myMethod[T](param: T)(implicit oneOf: OrElse[TypeClass1[T], TypeClass2[T]]) = ???
// def myMethod[T](param: T)(implicit oneOf: Priority[TypeClass1[T], TypeClass2[T]]) = ???
// def myMethod[T](param: T)(implicit oneOf: Or[TypeClass1[T], TypeClass2[T]]) = ???

trait TypeClass1[T]
trait TypeClass2[T]
implicit val tc1: TypeClass1[Int] = ???
implicit val tc2: TypeClass2[String] = ???
myMethod(1) //compiles
myMethod("a") //compiles
```

Type classes `OrElse`, `Priority` are similar to `UnionTypeClass` from **@Tim**'s answer but they prioritize `t1`, `t2`.