# How to determine if a class is a subclass of a parent class or trait?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-reflect

In Scala, how can we determine if a class is a subclass of a parent class or a trait? For example:

```
trait MyTrait
class MyParentClass()
class MyOtherParentClass()

case class MySubClass() extends MyParentClass with MyTrait
case class MyOtherSubClass() extends MyOtherParentClass
```

Is it possible to identify if class such as `MySubClass` extends from `MyParentClass` or `MyTrait` without instantiating an object and through reflection APIs? Given an unknown generic type `T`, I am interested in having it match a case if `T` extends a particular parent class or a trait:

```
def example[T](): Unit = {
    T match {
      case if T extends MyParentClass => ...
      case if T extends MyOtherParentClass => ...
      case if T extends MyOtherTrait => ...
      case _ => default case ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write

```
case class MySubClass() extends MyParentClass with MyTrait
```

then obviously `MySubClass` extends `MyParentClass` and `MyTrait` so you can check that for a generic type `T` with

```
def test[T](implicit ev: T <:< MyParentClass, ev1: T <:< MyTrait) = ???

test[MySubClass] // compiles
```

at compile time.

---

If the thing is you want to check that with OR instead of AND, then you can use `shapeless.OrElse` or `implicitbox.Priority`

[Scala method that needs either one of two implicit parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060507/scala-method-that-needs-either-one-of-two-implicit-parameters)

---

> I updated the question with an example of the desired usage

It seems you want a type class

```
trait Example[T] {
  def example(): Unit
}
object Example {
  implicit def subtypeOfMyParentClass[T <: MyParentClass] = new Example[T] {
    override def example(): Unit = ???
  }

  implicit def subtypeOfMyOtherParentClass[T <: MyOtherParentClass] = new Example[T] {
    override def example(): Unit = ???
  }

  implicit def subtypeOfMyOtherTrait[T <: MyOtherTrait] = new Example[T] {
    override def example(): Unit = ???
  }

  implicit def default[T] = new Example[T] {
    override def example(): Unit = ???
  }
}

def example[T]()(implicit e: Example[T]): Unit = e.example()
```

A type class is a compile-time (i.e. type-level) replacement for pattern matching.

If there is ambiguity among implicits you can prioritize them.

---

> Just curious, do you know if there is a way to do this in a simple one line conditional such as `if (T extends from MyParentClass) then ...` through reflection APIs (is it possible through `classOf[]` or `typeOf[]`?)

You can do that at runtime

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def example[T: TypeTag](): Unit = 
  if (typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyParentClass]) ???
  else if (typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyOtherParentClass]) ???
  else if (typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyOtherTrait]) ???
  else ???
```

or

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def example[T: ClassTag](): Unit = 
  if (classOf[MyParentClass] isAssignableFrom classOf[T]) ???
  else if (classOf[MyOtherParentClass] isAssignableFrom classOf[T]) ???
  else if (classOf[MyOtherTrait] isAssignableFrom classOf[T]) ???
  else ???
```

or at compile time

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def example[T](): Unit = macro exampleImpl[T]

def exampleImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  if (weakTypeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyParentClass]) ???
  else if (weakTypeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyOtherParentClass]) ???
  else if (weakTypeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyOtherTrait]) ???
  else ???
}
```

But implicits and types is a preferable way rather than (compile-time or especially runtime) reflection. It's not clear why you need reflection at all.

https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-to-access-the-method/6281

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with an example of the desired usage

Comment: Thanks, this is a neat solution. Just curious, do you know if there is a way to do this in a simple one line conditional such as `if (T extends from MyParentClass) then ...` through reflection APIs (is it possible through classOf[] or typeOf[]?)